# Is my function injective?

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Given the set $A=\{x \in (0,1): \sin(1/x)=0\}$, find an injective function $f:A→ \Bbb N$.

My attempt:

Let the function be $f(x) = \frac{1}{\arcsin(x)}$

This implies

$$f\left(\frac{1}{\arcsin(x)}\right) = \frac{1}{\arcsin\left(\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)} = x$$

Is this correct or am not understanding this correctly? Can a subset of real numbers have an injection to the set of natural numbers?

Comment: Is the set $A$ supposed to be the set of all numbers of the form $\sin(1/x)$, where $x\in (0,1)$? If not, then I think the $\sin(1/x)$ part should be some condition, like the equation $\sin(1/x)=0$.

Comment: Do you mean $A=\{\sin(1/x) \text{ s.t. } x \in (0,1) \}$? How you’ve defined $A$ at the moment doesn’t really make sense

Comment: You are right, I missed it when I wrote it out so to be clear. It is sin(1/x) = 0

Comment: To answer your last question, yes, because any injection from $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ proves it.

Comment: For a real number $\theta$ one has $\sin(\theta) = 0 \iff (\exists k \in \mathbb Z) \ \theta = 2k\pi$. Thus, $A = \{x \in (0,1) : (\exists k \in \mathbb Z) \ \frac 1x = 2k\pi\} = \big\{\frac1{2k\pi} : k \in \mathbb N\big\}.$

Comment: Can I answer this question like this given what you said here @azif00:
Let the injective function be $f(x) = 1/|2\pi x|$
Since, $sin(1/x)=0$ iff  $x = 1/2\pi k$ when $x\in\{0,1\}$ it implies, 
$f(1/2\pi k) = |2\pi k|/(2\pi) = k \in \Bbb Z^+ =\aleph_0$

Comment: I think it can do without the absolute value in f(x)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: $\sin \theta = 0$ iff $\theta = k\pi$ for some integer $k$. Thus, $A = \{\frac1{n\pi} : n \in \mathbb N\}$, and then the function $A \to \mathbb N$ that sends the element $\frac1{n\pi}$ of $A$ to $n$ is injective.